# Is there a way to format the count for rows affected in DataGrip?

Tags: sql, formatting, datagrip

Is there a way to format the count for *rows affected*, that is returned to the Output console?

[image]

I would like the "451903055" to be formatted "451,903,055" (or whatever i18n) for faster readability.  Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way now to do that :(

Comment: PMM at DataGrip.  I'll take your word for it.  Hopefully it can be a little backlog item! :)